# How to change cell reuse behaviour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a `tableView`in which I use cell reuse. 
When I scroll very fast, I can see for a slight moment labels and other contents from previous cells being displayed on newly generated cells.

It can appear buggy for end users, and I am looking for a way to cache or load cells just before they are visible to avoid this.

I also wrote a reset function :

```
func resetCell(cell: UITableViewCell){
        for v in cell.contentView.subviews{
            if let v = v as? UILabel{
                v.text = ""
            }else if let v = v as? UIImageView{
                v.image = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

But it wasn't a success...

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reset content you should override method `- (void)prepareForReuse;` on your **UITableViewCell** or **UICollectionViewCell** subclass. Here is an example of doing that:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    _imageView.image = nil;
    _asset = nil;

    [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

Also, if you have any download related to this cell - prepareForReuse is the best place to cancel that.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for ! Unfortunately, it brings others problems that I didn't expect( if I scroll up and down very fast few times, all content disapears and doesn't reappear..)

Comment: Could you please show how you setup cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: Sure :    

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       
 let cell =tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ConversationCell") as! ConversationCell

        cell.character = character[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
        cell.isVisible = isVisible
        
        return cell
    }`

Comment: What does cell.isVisible do? When you say "All content disappears and doesn't reappear" you mean all cells become invisible or cells appear but no content is visible? Try to make cell.backgroundColor = .redColor() just to debug and see what happens.

Comment: `cell.isVisible` is a bool set to true when the `tableViewController` is visible and false when not (as cells perform individually network requests, and perform fading between pictures, I only want this to happen when the tableview is visible.. every thing is embedded in a `UIPageViewController`, that's why sometimes it is not visible). when I change the background color, it's correctly set .. only the labels and images are not reloaded after a while

Comment: Make sure that updates you are doing on main thread, plus make sure when you do `cell.character = character[indexPath.row]` you correctly load data and make all required items visible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `prepareForReuse` function for the cell. Inside of this function you can then reset any text labels to empty strings (or whatever else you have in the cell).

This will ensure that when the table view reuses the cell, you won't see the previous cells data.

Answer (score 0):

```
func resetCell(inCell: UITableViewCell){
    if let cell = inCell {
        cell.contentView = nil;
        cell.removeFromSuperview();
    }
}
```